# is it possible add customized functionalities to website?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, web

I want to create something that can help me learn a language. In the online web dictionaries, when you look for a word, it shows you the word with an audio option. I have to click it each time I want to hear it. I want to make it so that there is "number of time" option that you can enter beside the audio option so that the audio will repeat itself n times after I press it. Also, I want to make it so that the example sentences could be heard as well.

I know basic java, python, c, Ocaml. If anyone can point to the right direction, that would be appreciated. (I thought it could be as simple as modifying source HTML and write a program on your computer that executes it? I have no idea.)

Another example, create a customized button in the Tinder to swipe for you.

Answer (score 2):

As fa as I know, both the audio and video have the loop attribute, so, you could set this attribute to playing the audio/video over again

Reference: [HTML  loop Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_loop.asp) and [Audio loop Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_audio_loop.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty simple. I believe you would have a function which when called (upon a button click as you stated) starts the audio for the specific word. You can have a `<select>` with options for example: 1,2,3,4,5... You can take the value with javascript using the `.getElementById(elementsId).value` You can then make the function I talked about earlier get called the number of times the user inputted. This can be done with a for loop (Placing the audio function into a for loop with the number of times it being looped being the user input number).

Comment: Thanks! I'm not very familiar with Javascrip, Would you recommand me some readings/online tutorials on how to do it? I just don't know where to start.

Comment: Yes, javascript knowledge is definitely required in order to do what you are willing to do in my opinion. Since you have knowledge with other programming languages you should be able to understand and learn it easier. I would recommend whatching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdI2bqOjy3c